# Specify valid generic types with a parameter

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following classes

```
public interface SortBy<S> {
}

public class CommentSortBy<S> implements SortBy<S> {
    public static CommentSortBy<Date> CREATION = new CommentSortBy<Date>();
    public static CommentSortBy<Integer> VOTES = new CommentSortBy<Integer>();
}

public class SomeQueryUnsafe {
    public <M, S extends SortBy<M>> void setSort(S sortBy, M min) {
        //Set relevant values
    }
}
```

This is currently used as:

```
public SomeQueryUnsafe createCommentQueryUnsafe() {
    return new SomeQueryUnsafe();
}

public void test() {
    createCommentQueryUnsafe().setSort(CommentSortBy.CREATION, new Date());
}
```

While this works, the problem is that `createCommentQueryUnsafe()` does not specify limits on `sortBy`. Users are free to pass `UserSortBy.NAME` even though that would make no sense in this context

I can't figure out how to do write this though because just adding `<B extends SortBy>` to the class signature means I loose the ability to restrict the `min` parameter in the method. I can't use something like `<M, S extends B & SortBy<M>>` as [its a compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197190/why-cant-i-use-a-type-argument-in-a-type-parameter-with-multiple-bounds). Other attempts with wildcard magic just result in significantly more complexity and compiler errors. Moving the sorting to the `createCommentQuery()` method would mean every single query needs 2 methods, which is a crazy amount of duplicated code

How can I possibly write the generics so `createCommentQuery()` limits the `sortBy` parameter to just `CommentSortBy` while still having `min` restricted to the S parameter in the SortBy class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a tricky issue for the reasons you've pointed out. I tried various approaches but they were all defeated by the [generics limitation you cited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197190/why-cant-i-use-a-type-argument-in-a-type-parameter-with-multiple-bounds). Ultimately it seems like you'll need to make some design changes if you want the specified type safety.

Using the inheritance hierarchy of the `SortBy` implementations for your generic type restrictions seems to have led to this impasse in particular. I tried decoupling that restriction into a new type parameter on `SortBy`, which stands for the queried object itself, e.g. `Comment`, `User`, etc. This is the design I came up with:

```
static class Comment { }

static class User { }

interface SortBy<T, M> { }

static class CommentSortBy<M> implements SortBy<Comment, M> {

    static final CommentSortBy<Date> CREATION = new CommentSortBy<Date>();
    static final CommentSortBy<Integer> VOTES = new CommentSortBy<Integer>();
}

static class UserSortBy<M> implements SortBy<User, M> {

    static final UserSortBy<String> NAME = new UserSortBy<String>();
}

static class Query<T> {

    public <M> void setSort(SortBy<T, M> sortBy, M min) {
        //Set relevant values
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Query<Comment>().setSort(CommentSortBy.CREATION, new Date());
    new Query<Comment>().setSort(UserSortBy.NAME, "Joe"); //compiler error
}
```

([ideone](http://ideone.com/1QO9mG))

Comment: First, there are many "create" methods: `createUserQuery()`, `createCommentQuery()`, etc. Each needs to create a query that restricts the sortBy values to its specific context. All you've done is made the create method return the generic version, which still lets `createCommentQuery()` accept `UserSortBy.NAME`, a completely invalid value for comments.

Comment: Ideally `createCommentQuery()` would return something like `SomeQuery<CommentSortBy>`, which means sortBy would only accept `sortBy(CommentSortBy.CREATION, someDate)` and `sortBy(CommentSortBy.VOTES, 5L)`, but not `sortBy(UserSortBy.NAME, "Sam")`

Comment: @TheLQ That makes sense, but wouldn't calling `SomeQueryUnsafe.<CommentSortBy<Object>, Object>create()` come close to imposing that restriction? (ignoring for the moment the inflexible `M` parameter).

Comment: Correct, if I didn't need M then it would be a simple `<S extends SortBy>`. I just loose compile time checking (and IDE autocompletion) of the `min` and `max` parameters. I'm really trying to avoid that though

Comment: @TheLQ I see the issue clearly now, and it's definitely a tricky one. Thanks for your patience with me.

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty ingenious solution, so +1 (and the accept in a day or two if no more answers are posted) from me. This is defiantly something I'll be saving for later. The only reason I can't do it in my situation is the complexity of the sort API I'm working with (the StackExchange API), where some queries that return `Comment`s have different acceptable `sortBy` values. The object graph starts to get really complex with your solution. Thank you though so much for the idea though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Most likely I'm going to use an idea I had after I posted the question: move setting `min` and `max` values to the `CommentSortBy` class. This allows some more flexibility (and less generics soup) at the expense of more awkward api. It was something I was trying to avoid but it looks like at this point there is no other option

Comment: @TheLQ Glad I could help. You should definitely post your own solution as an answer if you get a chance.

Comment: and of course the `S` is unnecessary. The `setSort` above can be declared as `public <M> void setSort(SortBy<T, M> sortBy, M min)`