# Java generics - reference type parameter of type parameter

Tags: java, oop, generics

Let's say I have two interfaces, Foo and Bar:

```java
interface Foo<T extends Bar<U>, U> {
    T getBar();

    default U get() {
        return getBar().get();
    }
}

interface Bar<U> {
    U get();
}
```

The implementations would look like this:

```java
class BarImpl implements Bar<String> {
    @Override
    String get() {
        return "bar";
    }
}

class FooImpl implements Foo<BarImpl, String> { // Specifying String here is redundant, we know that BarImpl implements Bar<String>
    @Override
    public BarImpl getBar() {
        return new BarImpl();
    }
}
```

Ideally, `Foo` could be defined with just a single specified type parameter (`T`) and `U` could be inferred, so the declaration of FooImpl could simply be `class FooImpl implements Foo<BarImpl>`. At this point though, so that we may use `U` in the `Foo` interface, we require a secondary parameter. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are implicit generics in classes not allowed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54139983/1553851)

Comment: since you *want* to distinguish between `T` and `U` (in `Foo` interface), no way around this....but you can (if) re-design your api, and return `Bar` instead of `U`