# java generics multiple class bounds

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming

Suppose I have some Java code like this (won't compile):

```
class MyGenericClass<T extends SomeInterface, U extends SomeClass & T>{}
```

The trouble is, I can't declare U as is, because when listing bounds, the class must come first, and T might be a class.  Is there an obvious work around here?  If not, it seems that you'd be forced into doing unchecked casts sometimes, which is unfortunate.

Comment: Do you need the specific `T` in your class's logic, or do you just care that `T` extends `SomeInterface`?

Comment: need T as the return type of a public method

Comment: Lets say `T` gets specified as class how will Java be able to allow `U` extend both SomeClass and that `T` class.

Comment: If `T` is a class, it _must_ be either a superclass or a subclass of `SomeClass`, or there's no possible `U`.  Do you know which one it will be?

Comment: T is an ancestor of U

Comment: @MarkVY the compiler thinks that it might be a class and hence complaining, but actually in your use-case, is it always an interface or can it be a class as well?

Comment: Why does your class need to return an object as `T` and not as `SomeInterface`? Maybe you should restructure the class hierarchy. I don't think we can help you further without more context on why you need to keep this invariant

Comment: What is `SomeClass & T` ? Are you allowed to use `&` in Generics, never seen it before?

Comment: @Kartik it's always either SomeInterface, or else SomeFancierVersionOfTheInterface.  Pretty sure it's never a concrete class, though I might be wrong.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197190/why-cant-i-use-a-type-argument-in-a-type-parameter-with-multiple-bounds

Comment: @flakes : why should the caller be forced to write explicit casts?

Comment: @KorayTugay https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html

Comment: @MarkVY I see, thanks. Never seen it before..