# Generics that extends more than one type

Tags: java, java-6

Assign to a variable an object that extends a class and implements an Interface at the same time.
I have a method like this

```
public static <T extends Component & MyInterface> T instance() {
  if (test1) return new MyLabel();
  if (test2) return new MyCombo();
  if (test3) return new MyText();
}

class MyLabel extends JLabel implements MyInterface {
  ...
}

class MyCombo extends JComboBox implements MyInterface {
  ...
}

class MyText extends JTextField implements MyInterface {
  ...
}
```

this means the instance() returned object is a Component AND implements MyInterface.
and I can do something like

```
instance.setEnable(true); // calling a Component method
instance.foo();           // calling a MyInterface method
```

Now I want to assign the returned value to a variable: how to declare the variable in order to bring with the variable all the Generics info?

I expect to be able to do something like this:

```
static <T extends Component & MyInterface> T myVar = instance();
myVar.setEnable(true); // calling a Component method
myVar.foo();           // calling a MyInterface method
```

and also this:

```
static void f1(Component c) {}
static void f2(MyInterface c) {}
f1(myVar);
f2(myVar);
```

In my opinion the question is different from the one in [Why can't I use a type argument in a type parameter with multiple bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197190/why-cant-i-use-a-type-argument-in-a-type-parameter-with-multiple-bounds) because I'm not using a type parameter inside a generic class declaration.

Comment: Can't `Component` implement `MyInterface`? If no, maybe you'd need a subclass of `Component` that does implement `MyInterface`...

Comment: What does `instance()` method look like?

Comment: @Eran instance() create an Object of a class that extends Component (JLabel, JTextField or any other Swing/AWT Component) and also implements MyInterface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I use a type argument in a type parameter with multiple bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197190/why-cant-i-use-a-type-argument-in-a-type-parameter-with-multiple-bounds)

Comment: More specifically, the reasons are mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/210992/180719

Comment: @Olivier sorry maybe I don't understand exactly the answer you point but it seems a bit different. In my question I can compile and use without errors the instance() method. I'm not able to assign the returned value to a variable.

Comment: I edited my question in order to be more precise (I hope)

Comment: There is a fundamental misconception. A method like `<T extends Component & MyInterface> T instance()` does not say “I’m returning something unspecified that is a subtype of `Component` and `MyInterface`”. Instead, it says “I will return anything the caller wants, as long as it is a subtype of `Component` and `MyInterface`”. So you can write, e.g. `MyLabel var = instance();` regardless of what the method actually returns. You should have “unchecked” warnings in `instance()` precisely for that broken promise.

Answer (score 1):

Based on John Bollinger suggestion I do some other experiments and found a possible "solution" (however not as simple as I required).
But I think my wrap() method is different from what John meant.

```
public final class Wrap<X extends Component & MyInterface> {
    public final X x;
    public Wrap(X x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
public static <X extends Component & MyInterface> Wrap<X> wrap(X x) {
    return new Wrap<X>(x);
}

static Wrap<?> myVar = wrap(instance());
myVar.x.setEnabled(true);    // Component method
f1(myVar.x);                 // Component parameter
myVar.x.foo();               // MyInterface method
f2(myVar.x);                 // MyInterface parameter
```

Comment: You're right, that's different from what I was envisioning for wrapping. And better, too.

Answer (score 0):

> I expect to be able to do something like this:
>
> ```
> static <T extends Component & MyInterface> T myVar = instance();
> myVar.setEnable(true); // calling a Component method
> myVar.foo();           // calling a MyInterface method
> ```

I'm afraid not.  Java does not offer generic variables, and for the most part it wouldn't make sense to do so.  You may declare the type of an *instance* variable as a type parameter of its class, but you cannot give any variable its own, independent type parameter like you can a method.  There is no way to declare a variable that has two types.

If you want to be able to make use of both facets of `myVar`, as shown in the example, then its type must be declared as a *specific* type that extends or implements both supertypes.  There are two main alternatives for that:

1. Make the `instance()` method return such a type.  This is probably the most natural solution, since that method doesn't depend on `T` for any purpose other than to hang supertypes upon.

   ```
   public class MyInterfaceComponent extends Component implements MyInterface {
       // ...
   }

   MyInterfaceComponent myVar = instance();
   ```
2. Dynamically generate a wrapper object of such a type that adapts general objects that extend the class and implement the interface to a particular type that does so.

   ```
   MyInterfaceComponent myVar = wrap(instance());
   ```

The latter makes sense to me only if there's a possibility that you need to handle externally-provided objects that extend the class and implement the interface, but whose specific class you cannot control.

Comment: I edited my question in order to be more precise (I hope). I think you are right when say 'Java does not offer generic variables'. As of my knowings yours alternatives are very unmaintenable/boilerplate... (is there an elegant/generic way to implement a wrap() method?)

Comment: Java supports such variables in JDK 10 and newer, `var myVar = instance(); myVar.setEnabled(true); myVar.foo();`, but this shouldn’t distract from the general misconception: for generic methods, the *caller* decides which type arguments to use, e.g. I can write `Runnable r = instance();` too, as it is valid to substitute `T` with a type extending `Component` and implementing `MyInterface` *and* `Runnable`, without the need to prove that there’s a matching concrete type, as providing that is up to the implementation of `instance()`.